# How do I take the mean of a set of variables all across a third dimension?

Tags: matlab

I want to find the mean of a across all values of the third variable (which is time).

===

> > a = rand(2,2,2)

a(:,:,1) =

```
   0.2638      0.13607
  0.14554      0.86929
```

a(:,:,2) =

```
   0.5797      0.14495
  0.54986      0.85303
```

> > mean(a)

ans(:,:,1) =

```
  0.20467      0.50268
```

ans(:,:,2) =

```
  0.56478      0.49899
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mean` function can take in an argument to specify the dimension.  To take the mean along the third dimension you can use `M = mean(a,3)`

For example:

```
a = rand(2,2,2)
a =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0.98083   0.89986
   0.83187   0.81679

ans(:,:,2) =

   0.099544   0.038084
   0.026289   0.087522

mean(a,3)
ans =

   0.54019   0.46897
   0.42908   0.45215
```